# node.js resolve promise and return value

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I use the Microsoft bot framework to come up with a "simple" PoC bot. I used a [tutorial](https://chatbotsmagazine.com/a-nodejs-chatbot-tutorial-part-1-a2abd1b1c715#.xkoxkhin4) as a basis and extend it.

I've a couple of basic functions for differet intents (ie. greetings, goodbye, etc) and one with some more logic in it (reqstatus).

The simple ones (ie greeting.js) return the answer nicely but the more complex one doesn't (reqstatus.js). Running the main code of reqstatus.js (without the first "const getReqStatus = (entity) => {") in a standalone script works.

**server.js** (main) -> see call in "if (intent) {"...

```
const getFeelings = require('./intents/feelings.js')
const getGoodbyes = require('./intents/goodbyes.js')
const getGreetings = require('./intents/greetings.js')
const getHelp = require('./intents/help.js')
const getReqStatus = require('./intents/reqstatus.js')
... 
const bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector)

// Intents based on definitions on recast
const INTENTS = {
  feelings: getFeelings,
  goodbyes: getGoodbyes,
  greetings: getGreetings,
  help: getHelp,
  reqstatus: getReqStatus,
}

// Event when Message received
bot.dialog('/', (session) => {
  recastClient.textRequest(session.message.text)
  .then(res => {
  const intent = res.intent()
  const entity = res.get('request_number')

  console.log(`UserName: ${session.message.user.name}`)
  console.log(`Msg: ${session.message.text}`)
  console.log(`Intent: ${intent.slug}`) 

  if (intent) {
    INTENTS[intent.slug](entity)
    .then(res => session.send(res)) 
    .catch(err => session.send(err))
  }
  })
  .catch(() => session.send('Sorry I didn\'t get that. '))
  })
  ...
```

**greetings.js** -> Returns the string ok

```
const getGreetings = () => {
  const answers = ['Hi, my name is SuperBot. Nice to meet you!', ] 
  return Promise.resolve((answers))
  }
module.exports = getGreetings
```

**reqstatus.js** -> Does not return anything

```
const getReqStatus = (entity) => {
  var request = require('request');
  var request_number = entity.toLowerCase()
  var output = [];


  // Processing
  var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('netreqs.csv')
  }); 

  lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
  var jsonFromLine = {};
  var lineSplit = line.split(';');
  jsonFromLine.req = lineSplit[0];
  jsonFromLine.req_count = lineSplit[1];
  jsonFromLine.req_type = lineSplit[2];
  //...
  var req_lowever = jsonFromLine.req.toLowerCase()
  if (req_lowever == request_number) {
     output.push( `Your request ${jsonFromLine.req} was received`);    
  // simplified
  }
  });

  // Output
  lineReader.on('close', function (line) {
  if (output == '') {
    output.push( `I was not able to find a request like ${request_number}.`);
    }
  console.log(output); // list output 
  return Promise.resolve(output); 
   });
  }
module.exports = getReqStatus
```

I also tried to put getReqStatus in a function but that also didn't work. 
After a lot of trying and googling I'm still stuck and wanted to ask the experts here. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the problem is that your `getReqStatus` isn't really returning anything. In your example `getGreetings` function you're actually returning `Promise.resolve(answers)` as the return value of that function.

However, in your `getReqStatus` function, you just set up a listener lineReader `close` event:

```
lineReader.on('close', function (line) {
if (output == '') {
    output.push( `I was not able to find a request like ${request_number}.`);
}
    console.log(output); // list output 
    return Promise.resolve(output); 
});
```

You're returning a Promise resolved **inside the anonymous callback function** you're passing to `lineReader.on()` as second parameter. That is not the return value from the `getReqStatus` function itself, so that `getReqStatus` is not returning anything, as expected.

The code of that function runs correctly as standalone code, as you say, just because it sets the listener properly and it does what it has to do. However, that code just doesn't return a Promise when wrapped in a function.

What you would need is to return a Promise that wraps the `lineReader.on` close handler, like:

```
function getReqStatus(){
//...code

return new Promise( function(resolve , reject ){
    lineReader.on('close', function (line) {
        if (output == '') {
            output.push( `I was not able to find a request like ${request_number}.`);
        }
        console.log(output); // list output
        return resolve(output);
        });
    });
}
```

I say **would** because I really don't know if this code will work, I don't have any kind of experience with the Microsoft Bot framework and not used at all with the `readline` module. However, even if this doesn't solve your problem, I hope it will help you a bit understanding why your function doesn't return a Promise and how could you fix it.

Comment: `return resolve(output);` only needs to be `resolve(output);`

Comment: @Sergeon thanks a lot for your fast reply. Unfortunetly that doesn't work... also not with the suggested adjustment from Jaromanda X

Comment: It works fine now. The main issue was that the variable that my main script had to pass on was not ok. Thanks a lot for your supprot.